# Заменить определенную строку в массиве единицами

Tags: c

Ввести двумерный массив. Поменять местами строку содержащую максимальный элементы со строкой содержащей минимальный элемент массива. Если максимум и минимум находятся в одной строке, то заменить эту строку единицами.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
int n, m, min, max, maxrow, minrow,x; 
int i, j, a[n][m];
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    for (j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            printf ("a[%d][%d]= ", i,j); 
            scanf ("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    for (j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j]> max)
                {
                max= a[i][j];
                maxrow= i;
                }
            if (a[i][j]< min) 
                {
                min= a[i][j];
                minrow= i;
                }
        }
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
    for (j=0; j<m, j++)
        {
        if (minrow==maxrow)
            a[i]=1; //тут выдает ошибку incompatible types in assignment of ‘int’ to ‘int [m]’.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, в чём ваш вопрос?

Comment: не получается заменить строку единицами, выдает ошибку

Comment: Вам надо все элементы в строке заменить на 1. `if (minrow == maxrow) for (i = 0; i < m; i++) a[minrow][i] = 1;`